# Groupby n-largest based on one column AND CONDITIONALLY on the second column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

I have this dataset:

```
    individual  cluster  choice  benchmark_probabilities
0      9710535        0       0                 0.008647
1      9710535        2       0                 0.012558
2      9710535        2       0                 0.013894
3      9710535        1       0                 0.030648
4      9710535        1       0                 0.020298
5      9710535        1       0                 0.021444
6      9710535        1       0                 0.014804
7      9710535        5       0                 0.163837
8      9710535        5       0                 0.085191
9      9710535        2       0                 0.013272
10     9710535        2       0                 0.014684
11     9710535        2       0                 0.006987
12     9710535        2       0                 0.007387
13     9710535        2       0                 0.008940
14     9710535        3       0                 0.027746
15     9710535        3       0                 0.017345
16     9710535        3       0                 0.015545
17     9710535        4       0                 0.007449
18     9710535        3       0                 0.013382
19     9710535        4       0                 0.011559
20     9710535        3       0                 0.013091
21     9710535        4       0                 0.006438
22     9710535        4       0                 0.006089
23     9710535        4       0                 0.007768
24     9710535        4       0                 0.007348
25     9710535        2       0                 0.001479
26     9710535        5       0                 0.054764
27     9710535        5       0                 0.065420
28     9710535        5       0                 0.098600
29     9710535        5       0                 0.067577
30     9710535        6       0                 0.002158
31     9710535        6       0                 0.002041
32     9710535        6       0                 0.001694
33     9710535        6       0                 0.001602
34     9710535        7       0                 0.010075
35     9710535        7       0                 0.008076
36     9710535        7       0                 0.004485
37     9710535        7       0                 0.009090
38     9710535        7       0                 0.005834
39     9710535        5       0                 0.018973
40     9710535        7       0                 0.014945
41     9710535        7       0                 0.007159
42     9710535        6       0                 0.001624
43     9710535        6       0                 0.001535
44     9710535        5       0                 0.048068
45     9710535        7       0                 0.003548
46     9710540        0       1                 0.018614
47     9710540        0       0                 0.006515
48     9710540        0       0                 0.004040
49     9710540        1       0                 0.005489
```

what I want to do, is the following:

1. Group by `individual`, `cluster` and choose the top 1 of each group
   based on `benchmark_probabilities`
2. Select top 5 results based on `individual`
3. If one `individual` has less than 5 unique `cluster`,
   then fill in the remaining space based on `benchmark_probabilities`
   without taking into account `cluster`.

The result should look something like this:

```
    individual  cluster  choice  benchmark_probabilities
0     9710535        1       0                 0.030648
1     9710535        5       0                 0.163837
2     9710535        3       0                 0.027746
3     9710535        8       0                 0.015682
4     9710535       11       1                 0.050787
5     9710540        0       0                 0.004040
6     9710540        1       0                 0.005489
7     9710540        0       0                 0.006515
8     9710540        0       1                 0.018614
```

I have done the following, which gives me the 1st and the 2nd stages, but not the third one:

```py
data.groupby(["individual", "cluster"])["benchmark_probabilities"].nlargest(1).groupby("individual").nlargest(5)
```

But the result is not what I want, and it also looks ugly:

```
individual  individual  cluster     
9710535     9710535     5        7      0.163837
                        11       75     0.050787
                        1        3      0.030648
                        3        14     0.027746
                        8        49     0.015682
9710540     9710540     0        98     0.018614
                        1        101    0.005489
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is output from `data.groupby(["individual", "cluster"])["benchmark_probabilities"].nlargest(1).groupby("individual").nlargest(5)` ?

Comment: I added the result. It looks quite ugly and also does not add those "missing" options

Comment: Only I ask because I got different output, added to answer `print (df0)`

Comment: this is my bad. This "small" sample appeared to be too big for pasting here. It would disturb the eyes. So, I cut it a bit and calculated it manually :) but the script was run with the full dataset. I wanted to show this ugliness and the incomplete results

Comment: ok, so I hope solution working nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) instead `nlargest` because avoid lost `choice` column and also better performance:

```
df0 = (data.groupby(["individual", "cluster"])["benchmark_probabilities"].nlargest(1)
           .groupby("individual").nlargest(5))
print (df0)
individual  individual  cluster    
9710535     9710535     5        7     0.163837
                        1        3     0.030648
                        3        14    0.027746
                        7        40    0.014945
                        2        10    0.014684
9710540     9710540     0        46    0.018614
                        1        49    0.005489
Name: benchmark_probabilities, dtype: float64

df1 = (data.sort_values(['individual','cluster','benchmark_probabilities'],
                         ascending=[True, True, False])
           .groupby(["individual", "cluster"]).head(1)
           .sort_values(['individual','benchmark_probabilities'], 
                        ascending=[True, False])
           .groupby("individual").head(5))
print (df1)
    individual  cluster  choice  benchmark_probabilities
7      9710535        5       0                 0.163837
3      9710535        1       0                 0.030648
14     9710535        3       0                 0.027746
40     9710535        7       0                 0.014945
10     9710535        2       0                 0.014684
46     9710540        0       1                 0.018614
49     9710540        1       0                 0.005489
```

Then filter only rows from original not in `df1` and sorting:

```
df2 = (data[~data.index.isin(df1.index)]
           .sort_values(['individual','benchmark_probabilities'], 
                        ascending=[True, False])
           )
#print (df2)
```

Added t `df1` and get top5 values by `head`:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
        .groupby('individual').head(5)
        .sort_values('individual'))
print (df)
    individual  cluster  choice  benchmark_probabilities
7      9710535        5       0                 0.163837
3      9710535        1       0                 0.030648
14     9710535        3       0                 0.027746
40     9710535        7       0                 0.014945
10     9710535        2       0                 0.014684
46     9710540        0       1                 0.018614
49     9710540        1       0                 0.005489
47     9710540        0       0                 0.006515
48     9710540        0       0                 0.004040
```

Comment: I have a question regarding this approach. Lets say the `individual` has 2 clusters and the top probabilities are 0.5 and 0.03, but the first cluster has overall ' probabilities which are way larger than the top of second cluster. When we concatenate after creating `df2` and take the top5, we risk losing the 2nd cluster's top option here. Don't we?

Comment: @EmilMirzayev - hmmm, `df1` is top5 by `"individual"`, so `df2` only is used if some rows are missing (`9710540`), if not missing (`9710535`) nothing is appended.

Comment: I ask it because when I am creating `df2` it has all the remaining rows of the dataset, which is the intention. So, concatenation happens horizontally, and even those rows are added they are added after the `df1` results, so even if you are taking `head(5)` it does not hurt the result. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: @EmilMirzayev - I think yes, only added if not 5 values for `individual`, if `5 values` it ignore rows.

Comment: Sorry to bother you Sir Jez, May I know what is the website about you showed me in the morning ~ :-)

Comment: @YOBEN_S - It is printscreen website, but maybe because `.sk` (slovak domain) it was block for you ;)

Comment: @jezrael got you sir ~ thank you for the information ~ :-)